# HTML tags to highlight data in MYSQL and Crystal Reports

Tags: html, mysql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

This may be a duplicate but from what i have found i think it is slightly different.  Also didnt want to comment or add answers to articles already marked as "Answered"

I have a query that i have used in a Crystal Report.  I have concatenated a few columns together and have made some of them bold in CR easily enough.

However for ease of redevelopment of the Crystal Report (the code wont change much but the design probably will), i have now concatenated several columns and the ones already concatenated above, in to one column.

This creates a blob that i have handle with....

```
CONVERT(USING UTF8)
```

All well and good (sorry, convoluted intro!).

However i am now exploring using HTML tags within the MYSQL query to make things bold and insert spaces, breaks and non-breaked spaces.

The code i tried is below.

```
CONVERT( 
CONCAT_WS(' ',
        <b>c.codetext</b>,
        m.pcdose,
        SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcunit),
        SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcrout),
        SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcfreqcode),
        m.pcinstruct)USING UTF8) AS 'Drug Info'

From P_DRUGS
```

I know this doesn't work because i have tried it >:)....and i think it can be done successfully if the concatenated value is text, such as...

```
CONVERT( 
CONCAT_WS(' ',
        '<b>Paracetamol</b>',
        '500mg',
        'Orally',
        SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcrout),
        SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcfreqcode),
        m.pcinstruct)USING UTF8) AS 'Drug Info'

From Drugs
```

Can anyone tell me how (or if) you can use HTML tags to do the above and make certain columns bold etc?

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks - Typo.  Changed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out and it is embarrassing that i missed it before i posted.

Simply type up the code as you would like it to appear using HTML tags in the MySQL query.  As below.

```
Select 
<b>column_name_1</b>, column_name_2
from table_name
```

Paste that in to the Crystal Report command and create your report.
Then right click on the field that has the HTML on it, click 'Format Field' and under 'Text Interpretation' drop the box down and select 'HTML'

Painfully easy!

Hope it helps someone one day anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this do the trick? I can't test it as I don't have your table schema but using a nested concat should do the trick?

```
CONVERT(
CONCAT_WS(' ',
    CONCAT_WS('', '<b>', c.codetext, '</b>'),
    m.pcdose,
    SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcunit),
    SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcrout),
    SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcfreqcode),
    m.pcinstruct)USING UTF8) AS 'Drug Info'
From P_DRUGS
```

You could probably doing it using just one concat like the following example but then you would end up with spaces after your opening bold tag and before your closing bold tag.

```
CONVERT(
CONCAT_WS(' ',
    '<b>', c.codetext, '</b>',
    m.pcdose,
    SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcunit),
    SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcrout),
    SP_GETCODECODE(m.pcfreqcode),
    m.pcinstruct)USING UTF8) AS 'Drug Info'
From P_DRUGS
```

Let me know if either of them work :)

Comment: Hi Naqash - Thanks for your answer.  When i try the first attempt i get this.
"<b>A&H type 2 spacer device</b>1mLOrallyOnce a dayBlurgh Blurgh Blurgh"
That's what i was getting when i did it my way.
With the second attempt i get the same but with spaces.

Comment: For the nested concat_ws, why not just use `concat('<b>',c.codetext,'</b>')` ?

Comment: Contact = Concat.  Thanks, another typo.  Simply using concat instead of concat_ws wont work either because CONCAT doesn't skip null values.

Comment: @MikeDWakelyn Just to be clear, the concat works fine but when you display it on the page, it just displays as <b>.....</b> rather than making it bold?

Comment: Why don't you just bold it in crystal?

Comment: @Sun - I am trying to do as much of the formatting as possible before it gets to crystal.  I may use the same data for multiple reports which will differ slightly depending on department.  So i dont want to have to go through each one making the same adjustments. If i can get most of the text formatting done in the query then it will save me hours in the long run.

Comment: @MikeDWakelyn I've never used Crystal before but, I get the feeling that it may be escaping html entities when you print the data out? Is there a html entity decode function in crystal or a way to prevent the escaping of them?